# java calling app not able to comunicate with WCF service

Tags: java, .net, wcf, web-services

i have java appl using the rampart, metro, and soapui, open source utilities to connect to a .net wcf service

get error 500 response and message that the security validation failed. i am able to connect from the java server using a sample .net application and are able to connect.

whats the trick to get java to use .net services?

Comment: From my experience, I have found it difficult for Java to communicate with WCF services if security is enabled. I tried this using Apache Axis.

Comment: yes, but it should be doable. i would think this would be documented up the wazoo by now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to tweak the WCF service configuration to support the java clients. Install and use the [WCF Interop Express](http://wcf.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=WCF%20Express%20Interop%20Bindings) wizards to help you find the correct config. If you don't control the WCF service, you still should be able to use the wizards to create a sample config they could use.